# How to run a program from cmd.exe (Windows XP)?

Tags: windows, cmd

I sometimes need to run a program from cmd.exe. This only seems to work if this program is present in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

So I just copied the `.exe` file into this folder and until now that worked (for Python and one or two other applications). However, I think this is not the proper way to do it. And when I try this with `php.exe`, I get an error saying some `.dll was not found`. I suspect it has to do with relative paths.

Could anyone please point out the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your Windows version, you have to find the "Environment Variable" button (in Windows 7 is on "Advanced System Settings" inside "Properties" from "My Computer" context menu); in the "System variables" there should be a variable named `PATH`. You can edit it and add the paths you want to include separated by `;`. Then reboot and it should work.

In this way you include those paths in the set of directories where `cmd.exe` search for commands. In your example, the problem is that `php.exe` is found (since you copied it in `System32` which is in the `PATH`), but the `.dll` files are still on the php's installation dir, so you need either to run your program from that directory or to update your `PATH` including it.

Comment: I've seen that previously. If I do that, is it no longer a problem if `php.exe` is absent from the `system32` folder?

Comment: Yes, because you have added the whole `php.exe` directory in the path, so not only it is not a problem, you should remove it to avoid conflicts (the order of the paths in the `PATH` variable matters)

Answer (score 1):

You have to either move to the directory that contain the executable, specify the full path or add the directory to the PATH variable. For example:

Change directory and then run:

```
cd C:\MyOtherApp\
programfile.exe
```

Run the file using full path:

```
C:\MyOtherApp\programfile.exe
```

or add to PATH:

Right-click My Computer and then go to Properties
Select the Advanced tab and go to Environment variables. 
Find the one that says PATH and add your folder to it separated by semicolon (;) such as:

```
[someotherpathsgoesfirst];C:\MyOtherApp\
```

You can read more about environment variables at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519/en-us and specifically about the PATH environment variable at http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because the dll has to be in the same directory as the .exe. The proper way to run an exe is by browsing to it's directory and run it from there. You can set a new directory with "cd directory" example:
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\users
sets the new active directory to "C:\users". You can use "cd .." to go up one directory and you can type "dir" to get a list of items in your currently active directory. I hope this helps you on your way.

Comment: It is enough that the .dll files are on the PATH.

Comment: Do you really want to teach someone to put every dll they ever need for their programs in the PATH variable? Keeping the exe and the dll in the same location seems a lot cleaner to me, unless you create a custom installer that sets the PATH and copys the dll to system32 automatically.

Comment: No, it was just suplimentary info. Exactly, the .dll files can be put in system32 or in another folder at user's choice.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a non-full path, Windows searching an environmental variable called PATH.

In other words, C:\Windows\System32 is in the PATH and that's why it's searched.  Moving executables into there though is wrong.  Either navigate to the executable (`cd \path\to\folder`), or add the directory to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add the path of your `.exe` file to your PATH environment variable.

You can see http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm for details.